# Why is user_can_access_admin_page() an undefined function?

Tags: user-roles, capabilities

According to WordPress Developer Resources, the `user_can_access_admin_page()` function is still active and valid...

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/user_can_access_admin_page/

However, when using this in version 6.2.2 as below...

```
<?php if(user_can_access_admin_page()) { ?>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="/wp-admin/" class="nav-link" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">
            Admin Area
        </a>
    </li>
<?php } ?>
```

I get the following warning...

`Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function user_can_access_admin_page()`

Has this been deprecated and the docs not updated?

Comment: The function is included in a file that's not loaded on the front end, if that's what you're trying to do. Also note that it's for "whether the current user can access the current admin page", so if you're not currently on an admin page then it wouldn't work anyway. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Not being loaded on the front end makes perfect sense then. In which case I've found the current_user_can() function to be the one to use.

Comment: @JacobPeattie can you leave that as an answer rather than a comment?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Jacob Peattie: functions not loaded yet.

You will need to use hooks/actions (init, wp etc) https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

e.g.

```
function callMyMethod(){
    $userLoggedIn = is_user_logged_in();
    echo 'INIT Action: User Logged in: '.var_export($userLoggedIn, true);

    if ( is_admin() ) {
       $canAccess = user_can_access_admin_page();
     }
}
add_action('init','callMyMethod');
```

This answer is assuming you're creating a plugin and calling the function on the main/root page.

Comment: Sorry, hooks/actions I get mixed up so the link may be incorrect but hopefully my comments answer the question of 'why' its not found.